# Click on Button using AppleScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I am trying to click on a button to add a saved meal to my Fitbit account using AppleScript.  The script executes with no error but the script never executes the button to actually add the meals.

So far, in my AppleScript, I've tried the following with no luck:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById['logFoodButton.favoriteMeals_156535979'].click()" in front document
do JavaScript "document.getElementById['logFoodButton.favoriteMeals_156535979'].onclick()" in front document
do JavaScript "document.getElementById['logFoodButton.favoriteMeals_156535979'].submit()" in front document
do JavaScript "document.forms['add.favoriteMeals_156535979']['logFoodButton.favoriteMeals_156535979'].click()" in front document
do JavaScript "document.forms['add.favoriteMeals_156535979']['logFoodButton.favoriteMeals_156535979'].onclick()" in front document
do JavaScript "document.forms['add.favoriteMeals_156535979']['logFoodButton.favoriteMeals_156535979'].submit()" in front document
```

None of these have worked.  Here is the HTML code for the site:
[Image of webpage HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i5YS.jpg)

I am not an expert in either AppleScript or JavaScript but am technical.  I don't believe this button is part of a form and I can't see how to trigger the button.  Thank you for the help.  Let me know if I can provide any other detail.

Comment: I think the square brackets ought to be parentheses, i.e. `getElementById(...)`.  Then your first line should work.

Comment: Dangit...that did it.  Cheers my friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the square brackets ought to be parentheses, i.e. `getElementById(...)`. Then your first line should work